# Android keyboard appear automatically

Tags: android, button, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a disabeld EditText and an "Edit name" button next to it. I press the "Edit name" button and after i make the EditText enabled again i'd like for the keyboard to popup so the user can insert the text (without him needing to "click" the EditText because i'm using that action for saving what he just entered and making the EditText disabled again).

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks,

Andrei

Answer (score 1):

in the textView onclick method put this code.

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.youris);
text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                      EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.Id.yourid);
                       et.requestfocus();
        }
```

}